# How to Not clean Scanner buffer in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have something like this :

```
InputStream in = new InputStream(fileName);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
String nextWord;
String anotherWord;

while(sc.hasNext()) {
  nextWord = sc.next();
  ...
  ...
}

while(sc.hasNext()) {
anotherWord = sc.next();
...
...
}
```

The second loop will not work because the Scanner's buffer gets cleared after a token is read by `sc.next()`. How do I read the tokens without cleaning the Scanner's buffer, so I can use `sc` in the second loop?

Comment: The second loop will not work because your scanner has reached end of file and not because its buffer gets cleared. Re-initialize the scanner or change your whiles to if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can just reinitialize the scanner like this.

```
InputStream in = new InputStream(fileName);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
String nextWord;
String anotherWord;

while(sc.hasNext()) {
  nextWord = sc.next();
  ...
  ...
}
sc = new Scanner(in);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    anotherWord = sc.next();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 nextWord = sc.next();
 nextToNextWord = sc.next();
 nextToNextToNext = sc.next();

 anotherWord = sc.next();
 anotherOneWord= sc.next()
 anotherTwoWord = sc.next()
```

You do not need loop to read here, unless into an array or `Collection`.